# tflite Model works in python but not in android

Tags: android, kotlin, interpreter, tensorflow-lite, inference

i have a tflite model for semantic segmentation; when i tried the inference in google colab, it works fine but in android it doesn't. i have tried everything but i can't understand where is the problem plz help, here's the code i am running :

```
fun detect(bitmap : Bitmap?) : Bitmap? {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return null
    }
    val modelFile = loadModelFile(assets, MODEL_FILENAME)
    val interpreter = Interpreter(modelFile)

    val h = bitmap.height
    val w = bitmap.width

    val outputBitmap : Bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 160, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    // output shape: { 1 x 80 (width) x 160 (height) x 1 (output labels) x 4 (float32) }
    val outputByteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * 80 * 160 * 1 * 4)
    outputByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    // input shape: { 1 x 80 (width) x 160 (height) x 3 (rgb) x 4 (float32) }
    val inputByteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1* 80 * 160 * 3 * 4)
    inputByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    // 1- resize bitmap
    val inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,80,160,false)

    inputByteBuffer.rewind()
    outputByteBuffer.rewind()

        // 2- convert bitmap to byteBuffer
     val IMAGE_MEAN: Float = 128f
     val IMAGE_STD: Float = 128f
    val inputPixelValues = IntArray(80 * 160)
            inputBitmap?.getPixels(inputPixelValues, 0, 80, 0, 0, 80, 160)
            var pixel = 0
            for (i in 0 until 80) {
                for (j in 0 until 160) {
                    if (pixel >= inputPixelValues.size) {
                        break
                    }
                    val `val` = inputPixelValues[pixel++]
                    inputByteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` shr 16 and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
                    inputByteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` shr 8 and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
                    inputByteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD)
                }
            }
    inputBitmap?.recycle()

    // 3- run inference
    interpreter.run(inputByteBuffer, outputByteBuffer)

    // 4- convert byteBufferOutput to bitmap
    outputByteBuffer?.rewind()

    val pixels = IntArray(80 * 160)
    for (i in 0 until 80 * 160) {
        val a = 0xFF
        val r: Float = outputByteBuffer?.float!!  * 255.0f
        pixels[i] = a shl 24 or (r.toInt() shl 16)
    }
    outputBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 80, 0, 0, 80, 160)

    // 5- resize the output Bitmap 
    val resizedOutputBitmap : Bitmap? = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(outputBitmap,w,h,false)
    return resizedOutputBitmap
}
```

the input is a RGB image and the output is a grayscale image

you find here the inference for tflite model in google colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZrBXP5ymjFwoJ18N1guk8qbnxqBfpQFE

Comment: Upload the colab file for reference . Might be you are testing your tensorflow model and not tflite model and there might be an issue at the conversion step.

Comment: It is really difficult to debug the whole process. Have you checked the original Segmentation app here?
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android Check the lib_interpreter module

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar i don't think the problem is the conversion because i have already tested the tflite model in google colab and it worked

Comment: @Farmaker yes i did but it didn't help

Comment: You need to make the google drive file public for everyone's access